# Is there some data structure or database that can handle path expression statements and path expression queries?

Tags: database, data-structures

I need to model a graph (or could be seen as a recursive tree(s) since it typically as a single or small number of roots) based on things having children:

```
a hasChildren (b, c)
b hasChildren (d, e)
c hasChildren (f, g)
d hasChildren (h, a)
```

Now there are implicit paths, a/c/f and recursive ones as well: a/b/d/a/b/d/...

And then I need to set things on the graph via a path expression, both properties about them (these paths have color: blue, or such) and also changing their children--perhaps removing/hiding them, or adding new children.

By path expression, I mean something like this:

```
a/b/** -> color = "blue"
```

would mean that all paths that start with a/b/ have the property color = "blue". So, if I queried for the color of a/b/d/a/b/d/a, it would return blue. But if I queried for the color of just a, at this point there is none.

Other expressions might be:

```
**/d/h
a/b/[color="blue"]
a/**/h
```

So, that would be used to make statements. I need similar way of doing querying. I need simple queries such as:

```
a/b/d
```

and more complex ones like:

```
a/**[color="blue"]  -- descendants that have attribute color = "blue". This could be infinite in recursive case so we can put a restriction on this type of query to have it make sense, like does such a path exist, or just return first one or something.
```

Also, more nodes might be added at any time.

a hasChildren (b, c, x, y, z)

I need the queries after that to match appropriately all the statements. So in other words, I can't just run a query and set a property on all the results, since then it won't apply to new things added later.

And of course, I need it to be very fast :)  I would have on the order of 1000's of nodes, 1000's of path expression statements, and query on 100,000's of path expressions.

Is there something that handles this type of thing well?

I looked into RDF/OWL kind of thing but it doesn't seem to have any support for paths.

Comment: Is each path through the points distinct? e.g. is the following allowed? a/b/c/d/e, f/b/c/g/h, f/d/c/h/j. All three paths go through b/c, so just following parent-child will not identify a unique path, just all the possible connections. Should each path have a unique id?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. The three things you listed are three different paths because they involve a different sequence of parent-child. a/b/c is only the same as a/b/c (identity), but a/b/c and b/c and a/b and a/c are all different paths.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are talking about querying against inferences made against object relationships.  If so, you need to take a look at RDF and SPARQL http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/ and the whole field of semantic content.

Comment: RDF can't handle it on it's own, too low level. SQARQL is about querying which is not the problem. The problem is how to make a statement where the subject is the results of a query.

Comment: I just spent a bunch of time exploring Jena but I don't see anything about dealing with paths. I need path expressions and querying on path expressions and... I don't see anything about that kind of thing in the the Jena docs. And I don't find the rule/inference stuff in the graph db docs, so... can't seem to find a single solution that does both statements on path expressions and querying on path expressions.

Answer (score 1):

On a similar problem, I ended up implementing my own [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (in my case, in Java) with a Node class that contains Node children and is able to check if the leftover path matches it (which implies that all its ancestors green lighted their chunk of the path before it.

It's pretty fast and the code's quite compact. Hope it helps!

Comment: A Trie will handle a certain type of query well, but I'm looking for a general approach to far more types of queries and statements than that.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is exactly what you need but to me it sounds like oracle's CONNECT BY and START WITH clauses.

for instance you could have a table called NODES with these columns:

- ID as primary key
- PARENT_ID pointing to ID of this same table
- COLOR ... and whatever else you need

and then make this kind of query

SELECT ID, PARENT_ID, COLOR FROM NODES START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID

adding whatever clause you need i.e. WHERE COLOR='BLUE' 
it also has a nocycle condition for your a/b/d/a/b/d example

here's more info

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html

Comment: Thanks, but again, this is not handling both the making of statements on path expressions and then querying on those.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand of the question you want to model a tree that can support recursive.
I can answer from sql table design point of view. There are 2 ways to do this
1) use an adjaceny model where you will store the key in one column and the child in the other

```
Parent Child
Null   A
A      B
A      C
B      D
B      E
```

2) You can use a Left Hand Value and Right Hand Value as defined as a Nested Set Model and this has good performance. Read this article from the SQL guru Joe Celko and it will give you more hints
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: That models a graph/tree, but any graph db does that. It's the stuff on top of that I need to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Graph model is quite different from the relational model, I thing you should use some NoSQL db.

Finding nodes by partial paths is implemented in MongoDB, only for trees, but should by easy to write graph implementation on application layer: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB

There are few graph-oriented DBs:

- [Neo4J: Open source database NoSQL graph.](http://docs.neo4j.org/)
- [Dex: The high performance graph database.](http://www.dama.upc.edu/technology-transfer/dex)
- [HyperGraphDB](http://www.kobrix.com/hgdb.jsp)
- [InfoGRID - The Internet graph database](http://infogrid.org/)

Also recommend that you read this article: [Querying RDF Data from a Graph Database
Perspective](http://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~cgutierr/papers/eswc05.pdf), especially chapter **3.2** about graph query language

Comment: Thanks for the great information, but... I'm still not seeing anything about making statements based on path expressions that then are used when querying.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure about any pre-made stuff to handle this kind of problem, but if I was going to model a tree structure I would probably just create a set of c# classes (or some other object oriented language). The general idea is you set up a class for a node, then a class for the graph itself with functions to add nodes, remove nodes, find specific paths, etc (set the "colour" of paths). You could then even save matrices representing different graph structures and paths to a DB if that is what you are looking for.

It is hard for me to get specific when your question does not really specify what sort of approach you wanna take. Are you looking for something pre-made to do this? If not, check out this set of tutorials about creating graphs in c# (same concepts could apply to any OO language though). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379574.aspx

Comment: The question is how to accomplish the indexing to make the statements desired and be able to query with high performance. A graph alone would not satisfy that.